# Computer freezes, squares appearing and NVIDIA failing

Tags: windows-8, freeze, gpu

My computer has been acting weird all since I got it almost a year ago. I've been using both Windows 8 and Windows 7 on it, and the problem has occurred in both OS's.

Randomly, my computer decides to freeze up, and the monitor is filled with squares, and after a few seconds the screen resets and shows an error:

[image]

I have of course tried updating, but NVIDIA doesn't like me... In the end I decided to check DXDIAG, which also looks quite... weird?

[image]

I have the **MSI GeForce GTX 560Ti 1GB PhysX** GPU, and I'm running Windows 8 64-BIT. This "error" can happen randomly, both while playing games, browsing or just being on my desktop.
Anyone knows anything about this? Is my GPU failing?
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, it's failing. 
The other possibility is that it just isn't connected properly to your PCI Express Lane. I suggest checking that your GPU is connected properly. Or try a different slot if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try the tool [**Video Memory stress Test**](http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en). It looks like the RAM of the GPU dies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on Linux machine with 560Ti. It took me weeks to find out the solution. After hours of frustrating tests it occured to me that putting the driver into "persistent mode" helps.
Linux command for this is:

*/usr/bin/nvidia-smi -pm 1*

I believe there is some similar tool in Windows. 
I know this is old thread, but I believe this post may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try having a look at the install logs?

I got this off of the Nvidia support site for a previous version. you'll have to replace the versioning with the version of your download file.

https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/515380/official-whql-nvidia-296-10-display-driver-feedback-thread-for-nvidia-geforce-desktop-notebook-ion-g/

-Open a Command Prompt window.

-Navigate in the Command Prompt window to the folder where the NVIDIA display driver files were extracted to. For Windows 7 x64 for example, it would be:

C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\295.73\Vista 64-bit\English

-Run the following command:

setup.exe -log:"C:\NVlog" -loglevel:6

-We will need the file generated by the setup installer in the c:\nvlog directory. Also, please send us the setupapi log from here:

C:\Windows\INF\Setupapi.*.log

Answer (score 0):

Even I think its failing. I have hp dv26000 laptop with nvidia gpu. Many lines appear on screen and then computer crashes. This is when I am using nvidia display driver. But when I am using Microsoft default driver, the line appear but computer doesn't crash. Try Default Microsoft drivers by uninstalling nvidia drivers on windows 7 and check if the problem persists. Sorry you cannot play games on default drivers (no openGL).